# Storing Facebook and Google IDs in my database

Tags: php, database, facebook, api, oauth

Is it a good practice to store Facebook and Google ID numbers in my database after they used the APIs to register my website? Is there any better alternative for example a token which will be always the same according to the user's Facebook or Google account? I don't really understand. Do these ID's change with time? I'm using OAuth for PHP on both sites. I would like to ask your opinion guys.

I read in both documentations that I shouldn't store the user id. An alternative token is accessible for Google via the Javascript SDK but I don't find a solution in the PHP package.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

States at the id field in the reference:
The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps. Our upgrade guide provides more information about app-specific IDs

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people

States at the top of page:
Important: Do not use the Google IDs returned by getId() or the user's profile information to communicate the currently signed in user to your backend server. Instead, send ID tokens, which can be securely validated on the server.

Thank in advance,

Adam

Comment: the ids you get are exactly what you should store.

Comment: where exactly did you read that you should not store the user id? please add all relevant info to your question.